# How to turn off camera click sound on Samsung Galaxy S2?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, camera, tasker

I have a Samsung Galaxy S2 through boost mobile.

I want to get rid of the camera sounds. I bought Tasker, and set up the profile like I was told. Everything is on or off. But when I exit Tasker at first, it says "Active profile". Then, it then says "no active profile".

How do I get rid of this annoying sound? I did system sound, notification sounds, media sounds, and slient sound. But I still have the dang noise.

Please help.

Comment: You just need to put mobile in silent mode. It will disable camera sound.

Answer (score 1):

1. Have a look at [SilentCamera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=soft.kinoko.SilentCamera).
2. Alternatively, if your phone's rooted you can delete those files:
   /system/media/audio/ui/camera_click.ogg
   /system/media/audio/ui/camera_focus.ogg
3. XDA has a [mod](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2061692) for devices with custom firmwares.