# How to make stock Camera app silent when shot is taken without preventing phone call ringtone sounds?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, samsung, camera, custom-sounds, camera-sound

This question is basically the same as [this one](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/89/how-do-i-disable-the-click-sound-on-the-camera-app) but the canonical answer for that post is not compatible with my particular device for which a discussion and a solution can be found below.

I would often like to use the [Samsung Galaxy SIII Neo](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_i9300i_galaxy_s3_neo-6289.php) stock Camera app but would like to keep the sound it makes while pictures are shot on silent (so that when I take a shot people are not distracted by the sound so that the resulting pictures taken look more natural). However, I've figured out that to turn such sound off, out of the volume settings `Ringtone`, `Notifications`, `Media`, and `System`, it is the `Ringtone` volume setting which must be turned off for this to take place (click on any of the volume hardware buttons and then on the volume settings cogwheel to see these). Unfortunately, setting the `Ringtone` to silent means no sound will be made when a phone call is received.

So, I would like to know whether newer phones have a Camera setting menu list entry for enabling or disabling the sound specifically for the Camera application. And, if not, then I would like to know where to place a feature request width Samsung for this to be implemented in future releases of the stock Camera software.

Anyways, I think, as a hack, if one knew where the mp3 sound file for the camera app is stored, one could just deleted (or perhaps replaced it with an mp3 file producing no sound to resolve the problem). Anyone know where I could find such a file?

---

**UPDATE**: I've tried [rooting my device](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/102430/what-are-the-advantages-of-enabling-or-disabling-samsung-knox) and then following [this solution](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/89/how-do-i-disable-the-click-sound-on-the-camera-app) but I still get an error message saying the filesystem is read-only. Not sure if [Samsung KNOX](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/102430/what-are-the-advantages-of-enabling-or-disabling-samsung-knox) is causing this. Thank you for your replies.

[image]

---

**UPDATE**: Remounting the system with the following command as root:

```
mount -o remount,rw /system
```

Allowed me to rename the file, but it seems it's the wrong file as the stock Camera app still produces a snap sound when taking a picture after the rename. Candidate files related to the stock Camera app under `/system/media/audio/ui` could be the following:

- Cam_Start.ogg
- Cam_Stop.ogg
- Camera_click_short.ogg
- Camera_click.ogg
- Camera_empty.ogg
- camera_focus.ogg
- Camera_Timer_2sec.ogg
- Camera_Timer.ogg

I've tried renaming both `Camera_click.ogg` and `Camera_click_short.ogg` to `Camera_click.ogg.bak` and `Camera_click_short.ogg.bak` but no luck! Even after rebooting the phone, the stock Camera application still produces a sound when a picture is taken with the `Ringtone Volume` enabled. The `Camera_empty.ogg` sound file produces no sound; ideally I would like this one to play when the camera takes a picture.

Anyone know where the problem may be and how to fix it?

---

UPDATE: After installing the `BusyBox` app in order to have the Unix `find` tool and then running:

```
find / -name '*.ogg' > out.txt
```

the contents of `out.txt` were the following:

```
/storage/emulated/legacy/Ringtones/hangouts_message.ogg
/storage/emulated/legacy/Ringtones/hangouts_incoming_call.ogg
/storage/emulated/legacy/Notifications/Calendar Notification.ogg
/storage/emulated/0/Ringtones/hangouts_message.ogg
/storage/emulated/0/Ringtones/hangouts_incoming_call.ogg
/storage/emulated/0/Notifications/Calendar Notification.ogg
/mnt/shell/emulated/0/Ringtones/hangouts_message.ogg
/mnt/shell/emulated/0/Ringtones/hangouts_incoming_call.ogg
/mnt/shell/emulated/0/Notifications/Calendar Notification.ogg
/system/media/audio/alarms/Alarm_Day_by_day.ogg
/system/media/audio/alarms/Alarm_Morning_flower.ogg
/system/media/audio/alarms/Dawn_chorus.ogg
/system/media/audio/alarms/Daybreak.ogg
/system/media/audio/alarms/Sea_breeze.ogg
/system/media/audio/alarms/Serene_morning.ogg
/system/media/audio/alarms/Springtime_memories.ogg
/system/media/audio/alarms/Ticktac.ogg
/system/media/audio/alarms/Walk_in_the_forest.ogg
/system/media/audio/notifications/Beep_once.ogg
/system/media/audio/notifications/Hang_drum.ogg
/system/media/audio/notifications/Harp_glissando.ogg
/system/media/audio/notifications/S_Bubbles.ogg
/system/media/audio/notifications/S_Charming_bell.ogg
/system/media/audio/notifications/S_Chirps.ogg
/system/media/audio/notifications/S_Dew_drops.ogg
/system/media/audio/notifications/S_Flowers.ogg
/system/media/audio/notifications/S_Good_News.ogg
/system/media/audio/notifications/S_Harmonics.ogg
/system/media/audio/notifications/S_Knock.ogg
/system/media/audio/notifications/S_On_time.ogg
/system/media/audio/notifications/S_Opener.ogg
/system/media/audio/notifications/S_Postman.ogg
/system/media/audio/notifications/S_Pure_Bell.ogg
/system/media/audio/notifications/S_Temple_bell.ogg
/system/media/audio/notifications/S_Tickety_tock.ogg
/system/media/audio/notifications/S_Whistle.ogg
/system/media/audio/notifications/Sweet_favour.ogg
/system/media/audio/notifications/Whisper.ogg
/system/media/audio/ringtones/A_rustling_in_the_trees.ogg
/system/media/audio/ringtones/Basic_bell.ogg
/system/media/audio/ringtones/Basic_tone.ogg
/system/media/audio/ringtones/Beep-beep.ogg
/system/media/audio/ringtones/Beep_once.ogg
/system/media/audio/ringtones/Blowing_dandelion_seeds.ogg
/system/media/audio/ringtones/Break_of_day.ogg
/system/media/audio/ringtones/Breeze.ogg
/system/media/audio/ringtones/Bugs_story.ogg
/system/media/audio/ringtones/Chime.ogg
/system/media/audio/ringtones/Drifting_downstream.ogg
/system/media/audio/ringtones/Ecliptic.ogg
/system/media/audio/ringtones/Flying_in_the_sky.ogg
/system/media/audio/ringtones/Fog_on_the_water.ogg
/system/media/audio/ringtones/Glissando_tone.ogg
/system/media/audio/ringtones/Ice_blue_tone.ogg
/system/media/audio/ringtones/In_your_mind.ogg
/system/media/audio/ringtones/Journey.ogg
/system/media/audio/ringtones/Leisure_time.ogg
/system/media/audio/ringtones/Over_the_horizon.ogg
/system/media/audio/ringtones/Popcorn_tone.ogg
/system/media/audio/ringtones/Quantum_bell.ogg
/system/media/audio/ringtones/Rainbow.ogg
/system/media/audio/ringtones/Rainy_day.ogg
/system/media/audio/ringtones/Rays_of_the_sun.ogg
/system/media/audio/ringtones/Rolling_tone.ogg
/system/media/audio/ringtones/Scampering_tone.ogg
/system/media/audio/ringtones/Writing_adventure.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/Alert_on_call.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/Auto_focus.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/Auto_focus_error.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/Birdsong_by_the_lake.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/Call_Connect.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/Cam_Start.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/Cam_Stop.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/Camera_Timer.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/Camera_Timer_2sec.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/Camera_empty.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/Charger_Connection.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/Dialer_new.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/Dock.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/Fairy_fountain.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/Highlight.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/HoverPointer.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/Lock.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/Lock_none_effect.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/LowBattery.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/New_chat.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/Pen_att_noti.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/Pen_att_noti1.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/Pen_att_noti2.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/Pen_att_noti3.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/Pen_det_alert.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/Pen_det_beep1.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/Pen_det_beep2.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/Pen_det_beep3.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/Pen_det_beep4.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/Pen_det_beep5.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/Pen_det_noti.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/Pen_det_noti1.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/Pen_det_noti2.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/Pen_det_noti3.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/PowerOn.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/S_Beam_end.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/S_Beam_error.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/S_Beam_start.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/S_HW_Touch.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/S_SIP_Backspace.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/Sent_chat.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/Serenity.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/Shutter.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/Shutter_multiple.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/Sparkling_mist.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/TW_Battery_caution.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/TW_Battery_swelling_warning.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/TW_Call_Disconnect.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/TW_SIP.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/TW_Silent_mode_off.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/TW_Touch.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/TW_Volume_control.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/The_secret_forest.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/Undock.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/Unlock.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/Unlock_none_effect.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/VideoRecord.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/Voice_processing.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/Voice_start.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/Voice_stop.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/WirelessChargingStarted.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/Zero_Clickr_Ready.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/airbutton_close.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/airbutton_open.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/camera_focus.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/lens_flare_lock.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/lens_flare_unlock_silence.ogg
/data/media/0/Ringtones/hangouts_message.ogg
/data/media/0/Ringtones/hangouts_incoming_call.ogg
/data/media/0/Notifications/Calendar Notification.ogg
```

At this stage I'm not sure whether the stock Camera app is really taking the shutter sound from one of these `.ogg` files or whether the actual `.ogg` file is hardcoded into the stock Camera app's binary file.

Comment: [How do I disable the 'click' sound on the camera app?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/89/981) | [how to turn off camera sound besides lowering the volume on i9220?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/37810/981) | [Can I disable the camera sound in the new ICS camera app (in silent mode)?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/20117/981) | [How to turn off camera click sound on Samsung Galaxy S2?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/36838/981) | [How do I turn off the shutter sound for the Android camera?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/710/981)

Comment: I don't want to use a different camera app, I want to use the stock Camera app. I've tried the solution of renaming the `.ogg` file but no luck (see screenshot above).

Comment: Have you tried using Xposed modules, I think there's at least 3. You could even do that through tasker too. Wouldn't a logcat/full bug report state sound location?**** just comment to other answer, cool you found it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On my Samsung Galaxy SIII Neo (Android 4.4.2) I was able to solve my problem as follows:

```
C:\> adb shell
```

and then

```
# su
# mount -o remount,rw /
# cd /system/media/audio/ui/
# mv Shutter.ogg Shutter.ogg.bak
```

This solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure, but I think the camera shutter sound is hard coded and have a feature to disable it based on your location for legal issues (in some countries, taking a picture without making a sound is considered a crime and can lead to 6 months of jail).

But there is a simple way to disable this:

- install Xposed installer on your phone. Grab the apk file from [here](http://dl-xda.xposed.info/modules/de.robv.android.xposed.installer_v32_de4f0d.apk).
- download and install this [module](http://repo.xposed.info/module/ma.wanam.xposed).
- after enabling this module, you're asked to reboot your phone, do so.
- after the reboot, enter to the module's app and navigate in the app to find the right option to disable the camera shutter sound.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My Android version is `4.4.2` but I'm not sure if this help given that the Samsung Camera app is specific to Samsung and not part of the Android OS proper, AFAIK. Anyways, what are the names of the countries where this is illegal (would like to know just in case I ever visited one of these, thanks; after all, it would be enough to just turn the sound off and take a picture; if your reasoning is correct, the camera should be disabled when the volume is on silent for such countries (?)). Thanks.

Comment: I don't know for other countries but here in algeria I know it's a crime taking pictures without making a sound that notify people around you that you took a picture (peoples privacy ) I think it's dumb samsung left this hole or samsung did it on purpose ? not sure ,yes I see your point that the camera sound in disabled when in silent mod ,about the methode I wrote up here it work on stock apps ,it just tell the camera app that you are in a different region that allows silent photo shutter ,and the geo tags will not be affected by this work around

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was able to disable the camera shutter sound by renaming a different sound file. Anyways, as long as one knows the law they should be OK. Thanks.

Comment: YOU'RE WELCOME MY DEAR FRIEND ,can you tell me the name of the file you've renamed for future reference ?

Answer (score 2):

After typing `su`, remount system as read-write with

> mount -o remount,rw /system

Then make the steps in the solution. This should work.

Comment: I've tried your solution but after the renames, the problem persists.

Comment: Have you renamed Camera_click_short.ogg?

Comment: Yes, I've renamed both `Camera_click.ogg` to `Camera_click.ogg.bak` and `Camera_click_short.ogg` to `Camera_click_short.ogg.bak`. Any other ideas as to what may have gone wrong, or what else can be done? Could the `.ogg` file used by the stock Camera app be found somewhere else?

Comment: It's possible Samsung uses a different file.  While in `su`, try to do a search for all .OGG files like so: `find / -name *.ogg` and see if any of the file names look like they could belong to the Camera app.

Comment: Done this. Please see the output in my post.

Comment: Also, the *.ogg should be in single quotes (`'*.ogg'`) or the shell will expand the * on the command line, so the regexp will not be passed to the `find` command.

Answer (score 0):

Since Android P renaming the files in the UI folder does not work anymore. With Samsung devices for example, the sounds are hardcoded into the Camera App, for countries where taking silent photos is forbidden (EU countries regarding privacy laws), the switch in the settings to disable the shutter sound is also not available.

Unless we do a little magic (no xposed needed, only root access to the filesystem):

## add Call Recording en Shutter Sound options to your Exynos phone by adding 2 CSC options to cscfeature.xml

---

1. check your csc code (about phone > software information > service provider sw > last 3 letters: [CSC])
2. in root explorer goto: /system/product/omc/[CSC]/conf/cscfeature.xml
3. download OmcTextDecoder (https://github.com/fei-ke/OmcTextDecoder)
4. put the downloaded "omc-decoder.jar" in a folder together with the encrypted "cscfeature.xml" file on a linux pc
5. open terminal and cd to the folder where you have put the files
6. run: java -jar omc-decoder.jar -i cscfeature.xml -o cscfeature_decoded.xml
7. open the "cscfeature_decoded.xml" file in a text editor
8. add the following lines to the file:

> <CscFeature_VoiceCall_ConfigRecording>RecordingAllowed</CscFeature_VoiceCall_ConfigRecord>

> <CscFeature_Camera_ShutterSoundMenu>TRUE</CscFeature_Camera_ShutterSoundMenu>

9. save the file and rename your old "cscfeature.xml" to "cscfeature_encoded.xml"
10. encode the edited file by running the following command in terminal:
    java -jar omc-decoder.jar -e -i cscfeature_decoded.xml -o cscfeature.xml
11. copy the changed and ecoded file back to your phone: "cscfeature.xml" and backup the old one to "cscfeature.bak"
12. reboot and you will find the shutter switch in the camera settings!

extra options:
https://www.askvg.com/tip-enable-hidden-secret-features-in-samsung-galaxy-smartphones/