# What are the advantages of enabling or disabling Samsung KNOX

Tags: rooting, root-access, samsung-knox

I've rooted my Samsung Galaxy SIII Neo Android device by following this [XDA Developers link](http://androidxda.com/root-samsung-galaxy-s3-neo-gt-i9301i). I would like to know what Samsung KNOX is, and what the advantages of enabling it / disabling it are (as this is not discussed on the XDA page I just mentioned).

Also, if I disable Samsung Knox, then how can I reenable it at a later time?

The screenshots below show how I've used `Odin` on my PC to root my phone and what the `Root Checker` and `SuperSU` applications in use look like.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Knox) :

> Samsung Knox provides security features that enable business and
>   personal content to coexist on the same handset. The user presses an
>   icon that switches from Personal to Work use with no delay or reboot
>   wait time.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Knox) The manufacturer has claimed this feature will be fully
>   compatible with Android and Google and will provide full separation of
>   work and personal data on mobile devices and "addresses all major
>   security gaps in Android.

(Download [Android Terminal Emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm&hl=en)) then 
for `Disable` :

```
pm disable com.sec.knox.seandroid
```

and after disable,  maybe you need this again ;

`Enable` :

```
pm enable com.sec.knox.seandroid
```

And i suggest you, in the `SuperSu` never touch For Disabling the Knox.
it maybe harassment you and need for the second root process.(this is happend for me, but maybe you need to try it).
Also , read these articles :

[How to Disable KNOX Security](http://www.droidviews.com/disable-knox-security-service-on-samsung-galaxy-devices/)

[HOW TO REMOVE KNOX AND PREVENT POSSIBLE ROOT ISSUES CAUSED BY KNOX](http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-safe-knox/366118-solution-how-permanently-remove-knox.html)

[How do I Remove or Uninstall KNOX](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/howtoguide/N0000005/13093/159642)