# How to disable the "waterdrop sound" played when locking or unlocking the screen

Tags: lock-screens, audio, custom-sounds

I am running Android KitKat 4.4.2 on a Samsung Galaxy SIII Neo. I have installed the [Screen Lock Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.iglint.android.screenlockpro) app which allows you to log off by clicking a home screen icon or tapping on a notification drawer entry.

Now I would like to know whether I can leave the sound volume on, but disable the sound that is emitted when the user logs out / logs in.

I presume this can be done by renaming a sound file somewhere [using a similar trick as can be done with the camera app](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/102420/how-to-make-stock-camera-app-silent-when-shot-is-taken-without-preventing-phone/102469#102469).

Thank you for your replies.

---

NOTE: This question I am asking is the same as [this one for Windows 7 PCs](https://superuser.com/questions/988399/how-to-disable-the-sound-when-logging-off-locking-switching-users), but relates to Android devices instead.

Comment: On the LG X Venture, I had to go to Settings:Sounds and Notifications:Volume, and then turn down the volume slider for "Touch Feedback and System."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Settings → Device → Sound, and you will find under the Feedback section relevant options, such as Touch sounds / Play tone when the dialing keypad is tapped, and Screen lock sound which plays sound when locking and unlocking screen.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to edit any sound files as the Screen Lock app has provided this as an inbuilt feature to disable/modify lock and unlock screen sounds.

Open Screen Lock app and open Settings, scroll down to the bottom and you will be able to find the option to uncheck and turn off the sound when locking and unlocking the screen using the widget or notification bar.

[image: Screen_lock_Settings]

<sub>Screenshot - Screen Lock Settings - (Click to enlarge image)</sub>

Comment: Sorry but your answer does me no good. The settings you mention are disabled checkboxes by default. No matter whether checked or unchecked, my Samsung `TouchWiz home` seems to be emitting those water drop sounds when I lock and unlock, regarless of this setting in the Screen Lock app. Any idas?

Comment: @JordanJamingsons Then obviously the Screen Lock apps is not the culprit here. Have you tried to disable it in your phone settings? `Settings > Sound > Touch sounds` uncheck the option and check again.

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure what the feature you mention is supposed to do, perhaps it finds the sound file and renames it on some devices but not on my Samsung Galaxy SIII Neo. But if I knew where the file was, I could easily rename it to something else or replace it with a blank-sound file. Any ideas?

Comment: OK, thank you for your updated coment. I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off NFC in your phone. My phone did this because I slipped an NFC card into my case.

Comment: Oh, this was happening to me because I turned on NFC. Wow! Who would have thought. I think the subway pass is triggering it.

Comment: yes... the subway card + NFC was also triggering mine too

Comment: Credit card in holder with NFC caused continuous water-drops. Thanks!

Comment: This has driven me crazy for _months_ on my Note 8. Thanks @Simon!